# What are some convenient examples of so-called dissolved organic matter (DOM) for lab work?

Tags: catalysis, radicals, reaction-control

Background, I have come across a chemical reaction system, occurring in nature, that apparently involves the presence of dissolved organic matter (in a catalytic role).

My research returns, for example, the following as examples of DOM per an [educational source](https://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ss507#:%7E:text=Dissolved%20organic%20matter%20(DOM)%20consists,bacteria%2C%20algae%2C%20and%20plants):

> Dissolved organic matter (DOM) consists of soluble organic materials derived from the partial decomposition of organic materials, including soil organic matter, plant residues, and soluble particles released by living organisms, including bacteria, algae, and plants.

So my question is basically other than grinding up a plant,  are there other examples of dissolved organic matter that I can conveniently employ?

One idea is perhaps organic tea (which is still a bit general) as a dissolved organic colored solution.

But,  possibly better (in terms of convenience and reactivity) suggestions would be appreciated.

The cited reaction, by the way, is as follows:

> $\ce{ O2 + 2 .CO3- + DOM -> 2 .O2- + 2 CO2 + DOM }$

Namely, the conversion by the action of oxygen on the carbonate radical anion to the superoxide radical anion and CO2, all in the presence of DOM.

Comment: So you have no leads with regard to which class of compound (e.g. polyphenol) this might be? How about tannic acid?

Comment: Do have leads, for example, dark color and fluorescence, but these most likely alude to the photocatalytic properties of the DOMs as well. Also, mention of Fulvic acid. Interestingly, one reference mentions tree leaves (which of course, includes tea leaves, albeit, the latter are more processed). Likely, have to experimentally verify efficacy.

Comment: For example, did find an interesting reference on dissolved organic carbon (DOC )  here https://www.researchgate.net/topic/Dissolved-Organic-Matter. To quote:

"...the effect of DOC (made from tree leaves and peat leachate) on macrophytes. In our lab the concentration of DOC can be measured, but the DOC cannot be characterized"

Comment: Did find related work, to quote results: The results from this study can be chemically rationalized by a reaction scheme of (a) photodecarboxylation/ regeneration of carboxyl: CxHyOz(COOH)m + aO2 + (metals, hv) --> bCO2 + cH2O2 + Cx-bHy'Oz'(COOH)m-b(COOH)b or of (b) nondecarboxylation photooxidation: CxHyOz(COOH)m + aO2 + (metals, hv) --> bCO2 + cH2O2 + Cx-bHy'Oz'(COOH)m. at here https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15352449/ , which apparently could include vinegar plus a colorant for photo hv effect.